On the integer solutions of the equation $y^2 = x^3 + n$
Let $n$ be a nonzero integer. I am interested in the integer solutions $(x, y)$ to the equation $y^2 = x^3 + n$.
Let $S$ be the set of all integer solutions $(x, y)$ to this equation.
I am wondering is there any upper bound on the size of $S$ [depend on $|n|$], and is there any algorithm [or code] to obtain the set $S$ for given $n$?
Thank you for reading this post.

J. GEBEL, A. PETHO ̈ and H. G. ZIMMER. On Mordell’s equation. Compositio Math. 110 (1998), no. 3, 335–367.

The answers to this question discusses how to compute it for a given $n$.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell_curve

Thanks for all of you! Your comments are very helpful to me!
